# The Resource cannot be found. ASP.Net + jQuery

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am using jQuery to call a function from class L1.cs. The jQuery and function are:

```
     function CallData() {
        alert("hello");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/L1/GetLocation",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

The CS code

```
public class L1
{
    public List<Loc> GetLocation()
    {
       //some code
    }
}
```

For this I get an error: "The resource cannot be found."
Where I am going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to setup a webservice method.

Take a look at this article, it should help explain the reasons behind the attributes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=VS.90).aspx

Here is what your code should look like on the CS end (assuming I typed everything correctly)

```
public class L1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public List<Loc> GetLocation()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Alternativly you could use page methods, the syntax is similar. This will wire up some plumbing for exposing the method call to javascript.

```
public class L1 : Page
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static List<Loc> GetLocation()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for your reply.
I am not stting up a web service. Can't this be done without using web service? I mean, just a simple web app wherein, data retrieved using ado.net from C# is given to javascript using jQuery.